# During a VSTS build, using an npm script, how can I determine the branch that triggered the build?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, build, azure-devops

I am trying to create a JS utility to version stamp a VSTS build with details about the branch and commit id.

I have been using git-rev-sync which works fine locally. However, when the code is checked out using a VSTS build definition, the repo is detached, and I am no longer able to determine from the git repo itself which branch the current code belongs to.

git-rev-sync reports something along the lines of:
**Detatched: 705a3e89206882aceed8c9ea9b2f412cf26b5e3f**

Instead of "develop" or "master"

I may look at the vsts node SDK which might be able to pick up VSTS environmental variables like you can with Powershell scripts.

Has anyone done this or solved this problem in a neater way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build variables will be added to current process’s environment variables, so you can access `Build.SourceBranchName` build-in variable from environment variable:

PowerShell:

```
$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
```

NodeJS:

```
process.env.BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
```

Shell script:

```
$BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
```

Batch script:

```
%BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME%
```

You also can pass it through argument of task (`$(Build.SourceBranchName)`), for example, using Replace [Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace variable value to a file, then you can read the value from the file (replace `%{BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME}%`).

Comment: NodeJS: process.env.BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME was the one I was after. Thanks!